# Better way to make side-by-side DIVs in CSS

Tags: html, css

I have 2 DIV's that I want to be side-by-side **under all circumstances**.  So far I am accomplishing it like this:

```
<div style="float: left">
    <table> ... </table>
</div>

<div style="float: right; overflow: scroll; width: 1000px">
    <pre> ... </pre>
</div>
```

However, **I don't like that I have to specify an absolute width** in the 2nd `div`.

I just want the 1st `div` to be the minimum width to display the table and 2nd `div` to take up the rest of the space without overflowing.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind ignoring ie6&7, this will work nicely:

```
<div style="white-space:nowrap;">
  <div style="display:inline-block;"> 
    blah
  </div> 

  <div style="display:inline-block;"> 
    blah
  </div> 

  <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
```

There might be some ie hack that will make this work in that browser, check:
http://blog.mozilla.com/webdev/2009/02/20/cross-browser-inline-block/

Answer (score 2):

One way i've found quite versatile is to only float *one* of the divs. Float the left one and put *that* much padding on the right div. Here's an example of what i mean: http://jsfiddle.net/a6Bv8/ - i put one with an inner wrapper for borders or padding requirements to make it fluid, as well as the three column example..

```
#left { width:50%; float:left; }
#right { padding-left:50%; }

<div id="container">
   <div id="left">
       left left left
   </div>
   <div id="right">
        right right right
   </div>
</div>
```

This is nice, too, to do three columns. You can float the first div to the left and give it it's width ( say 200px ), float the right column to the right and set its width (say 200px ) and set the padding on the third div to padding-left:200px;padding-right:200px (or 210 if you want a gap ).

Answer (score 1):

When you say "rest of the space" what do you mean. If your table was suddenly 3000px, what should happen?

I think a solution might be to wrap them in a third div:

```
<div style="width: 1500px;">
  <div style="float: left"> 
    <table> ... </table> 
  </div> 

  <div style="float: right;"> 
    <pre> ... </pre> 
  </div> 

  <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
```